# Вернуть массив объектов класса

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть класс Field для которого я хочу написать функцию, которая вернула бы указатель или ссылку на вот этот член класса

```
CCell* Cell[DEFAULT_COUNT][DEFAULT_COUNT];
```

Вопрос банальный, но вот никак не получается написать эту функцию.

Моя попытка

```
CCell* CField::GetShips() {
     return Cell;
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите вернуть двумерный массив по одиночному указателю? Покажите ваш код, что вы хотите и что вы пробовали. Из описания ничего не понятно.

Comment: Коду, вызывающему эту функцию, необходимо будет знать не только указатель на первый элемент массива, но и размерность этого массива.

Comment: Может в вашем случае лучше использовать член класса в виде `std::vector<std::vector<CCell> >` и возвращать ссылку на него?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Соответствующая функция -член класса, которая возврщает ссылку на массив, может выглядеть следующим образом

```
CCell* ( & getArray() )[DEFAULT_COUNT][DEFAULT_COUNT]
{
    return Cell;
}
```

Или

```
typedef CCell* ( &RCell )[DEFAULT_COUNT][DEFAULT_COUNT];

RCell getArray()
{
    return Cell;
}
```

Или

```
using RCell = CCell* ( & )[DEFAULT_COUNT][DEFAULT_COUNT];

RCell getArray()
{
    return Cell;
}
```

В клиентском коде вы можете написать

```
decltype( auto ) rcell = objectOfTheClass.getArray();
```

или

```
RCell rcell = objectOfTheClass.getArray();
```

Или же можете явно определить ссылку.

Похожим образом будут выглядеть объявления для указателя на первый элемент массива

```
CCell* ( * getArray() )[DEFAULT_COUNT]
{
    return Cell;
}
```

Или

```
typedef CCell* ( *PCell )[DEFAULT_COUNT];

PCell getArray()
{
    return Cell;
}
```

Или

```
using PCell = CCell* ( * )[DEFAULT_COUNT];

PCell getArray()
{
    return Cell;
}
```

В клиентском коде вы можете написать

```
auto pcell = objectOfTheClass.getArray();
```

или

```
PCell pcell = objectOfTheClass.getArray();
```

Или же можете явно определить указатель.

Возможно вместо массива вам следует использовать другой контейнер, как, например, `std::vector` или, возможно, одномерный массив объектов типа `std::array`.

Например,

```
std::array<CCell*, DEFAULT_COUNT> Cell[DEFAULT_COUNT];
```

Comment: А как с ним потом работать?

Comment: @T2skler А я не знаю, как вы собирались с ним работать.:) Вы можете в клиентском коде объявить ссылку на этот массив и, используя ссылку, работать как с обычным массивом.

Comment: А если я перейду на vector, то не очень удобный доступ будет к данным. Сейчас можно запросто обратится к ячейке [x][y]

Comment: @T2skler Точно таким же образом вы можете обратиться к элементу вектора, если объявите вектор векторов. Также вы можете объявить массив элементов с типом std::array.

Comment: Не знал, что так можно с ним работать. Спасибо