# Работа с вектором векторов

Tags: c++, массивы, vector

В продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482330/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

Я правильно понимаю, что для того, чтобы перейти от обычного двумерного массива к вектору векторов, нужно зарезервировать память под него так?

```
Cell.reserve(DEFAULT_COUNT * DEFAULT_COUNT);
```

И передать так?

```
vector<vector<CCell> >* CField::GetShips() {
     return &Cell;
}

vector<vector<CCell> > * Cells = Field.GetShips();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы должны сначала определиться, что вы хотите именно вернуть из функции: либо копию вектора, либо ссылку на вектор.

Например

```
// объявление члена класса
std::vector<std::vector<CCell>> Cell = { DEFAULT_COUNT, std;:vector<CCell>( DEFAULT_COUNT ) };

// возврат копии вектора
std::vector<std::vector<CCell> > CField::GetShips() 
{
     return Cell;
}
```

или

```
// возврат ссылки на вектор
std::vector<std::vector<CCell>> & CField::GetShips() 
{
     return Cell;
}
```

или даже так

```
// возврат ссылки на вектор
const std::vector<std::vector<CCell>> & CField::GetShips() const
{
     return Cell;
}
```

Или может быть вам лучше написать оператор `operator []` вместо возврата вектора целиком.

Что касается памяти, то у вас вектор, как я понимаю, фиксированного размера. Поэтому можете сразу же определить вектор, как я показал выше, без раздельного резервирования памяти, а затем добавления по одному элементу в вектор.

Данное выражение

```
Cell.reserve(DEFAULT_COUNT * DEFAULT_COUNT);
```

было бы корректным при условии, что у вас "одномерный" вектор. У вас же вектор векторов, а потому для каждого вектора, вы должны отдельно резервировать память, если вы хотите это делать

Comment: Конечно лучше ссылку :) И как я могу инициализировать вектор при создании класса Field? Просто в классе нельзя проиницилизировать вектор так std::vector<std::vector<CCell>> Cell = { DEFAULT_COUNT, std;:vector<CCell>( DEFAULT_COUNT ) }; можно только так просто его определить std::vector<std::vector<CCell>> Cell;

Comment: @T2skler Если инициализация, которую я показал, не компилируется вашим компилятором, то вы можете  инициализировать вектор в списке инициализации конструктора или же просто в теле конструктора присвоить вектору нужные значения.

Comment: а каким образом? По сути мне не надо их инициализировать какими-либо конкретными значениями, они позже заполняются полностью другой функцией RandomShips() Как мне конкретно зарезервировать DEFAULT_COUNT * DEFAULT_COUNT памяти под них, чтобы потом не было проблем?

Comment: @T2skler Например, в теле конструктора можете написать Cell.assign( DEFAULT_COUNT, std::vector<CCell>( DEFAULT_COUNT ) );

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вместо того, чтобы сразу лезть в дебри стандартной библиотеки, посоветовал вам начать с малого. Хотя бы разобраться как работает сам вектор. Я вам даже маленький примерчик накидал:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class myClass{
public:
    int test;
};

int main(){
    myClass m; // временный объект самонаписанного класса
    vector<myClass> v; // временный вектор, необходим для создания новой размерности
    vector<vector<myClass> > theVector; // вектор векторов, который будет хранить самонаписанный класс

    m.test = 1; // задаем тестовое значение в наш экземпляр класса
    v.push_back(m); // кладём его во временный вектор

    m.test = 2; // то же самое, что и выше
    v.push_back(m); // то же самое, что и выше

    m.test = 3; // ...
    v.push_back(m); // ...

    theVector.push_back(v); // теперь кладём готовый вектор в вектор векторов
    v.clear(); // очищаем вектор для новых значений

    // повторяем помещение во временный вектор наших экземпляров класса
    m.test = 4; // ...
    v.push_back(m); // ...

    m.test = 5; // ...
    v.push_back(m); // ...

    m.test = 6; // ...
    v.push_back(m); // ...

    theVector.push_back(v); // снова вкладываем временный вектор в вектор векторов

    // ниже показано, как можно обращаться к каждому экземпляру, который мы создали и вложили в многомерную матрицу (массив)
    for (int i = 0; i < theVector.size(); i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < theVector[i].size(); j++){
            cout << theVector[i][j].test << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ничего резервировать не надо вектор сам все за вас сделает.

Comment: Зачем этот укоризненный тон? ТС задал конкретный вопрос: правильно или нет.

Comment: так на лицо то что человеку без нужных знаний пытаются объяснить более сложные вещи. все только что и делают это пытаются угадать а что же все таки нужно. а я дал дружеский совет без укоризненного тона. хотя можете забраковать мой ответ и гадать дальше